# Why is my INDEX/MATCH function returning a wrong value?

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am currently trying to make a sequence number generator in Google Sheets, and everything was going smoothly.

However, in the final steps, I noticed that one of my functions was returning the wrong value.
[image: Image 1]

As you can see in C9, it returns the AMS20-00001 value despite BBAS2 is not present in A12:A13.

I noticed this happened with some of my previous sheets before this, and it got me wondering what causes this? Shouldn't it return as #N/A or #ERROR instead?

I would be glad if someone could give me an explanation of why this happens as well as what can I do to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Applies to Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel**

> There are three arguments in `MATCH`

- Lookup value
- Lookup array
- Match type

`MATCH(Lookup Value, Lookup Array, [Match Type])`

> Match type is *optional* and accepts one of three values

- 1 = exact or next smallest (*default*)
- 0 = exact match
- -1 = exact or next largest

You've omitted the match type in your formula...

`MATCH(A9,$A$12:$A$13)`

This is the same as using the the default match type...

`MATCH(A9,$A$12:$A$13,1)`

*The exact match was not found so your formula returned the nearest value that is less than the lookup value*

**Using 0 forces the exact match**

`MATCH(A9,$A$12:$A$13,0)`

> In your example, this results in the expected error

`=INDEX($E$12:$E$13,MATCH(A9,$A$12:$A$13,0))`

Answer (score 0):

use vlookup:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A8:A10, A12:E, 5, 0)))
```

[image: 0]